# Transient analysis of the low pass RC filter

Tags: filter, ltspice, low-pass, transient, passive-filter

I have designed a low pass RC filter and trying to simulate using transient analysis. I can't figure out the magnitude of the input and output waveform. What's the time delay between the input and output waveforms.

[image: low pass RC filter]

[image: Transient analysis simulation]

[image]

Comment: Your voltage supply only has AC 1 listed for it. That's for the AC analysis. .TRAN will want to use something else. So add whatever it is you want (sine?) for the source supply.

Answer (score 2):

Click on Vin or Vout two times. You can use the cursor to find delay.